# IDLE won't open

Tags: python, windows-10, python-idle

I am very new to programming and I am trying to use Python on my computer. I downloaded and installed the program, but when I try to open IDLE, the Windows blue loading circle pops up and then disappears and nothing else happens. I'm using Windows 10 and Python version 3.4.3. I've tried downloading it from different sources, changing the path in environmental variables, repairing Python, and googling answers, but nobody seems to have the answer or even a similar problem. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have 64-bit windows? You might have downloaded the 64-bit version and your computer or OS only supports 32-bit. x86-64 is a 64-bit program, x86 and i386 is 32 bit.

Comment: I concur, this does happen at times.

Comment: How are you starting IDLE?

Comment: I'm not sure what Windows I have (32 or 64), but that may be it. When I was opening it, I was just clicking on the icon on my taskbar. I also tried running as an administrator in the files.

Comment: Note that if you're running 32-bit Windows 10 you'll need to use the 32-bit version of Python, but if you have 64-bit Windows, you can run either the 32-bit or 64-bit Python (each comes with a corresponding version of IDLE). Many folks use the 32-bit version because more third-party extension modules are compatible with it (and being able to "only" address 4 GB of memory is plenty). The best place to get Python is from [Python.org](https://www.python.org). There you can download either the 32-bit "Windows x86 executable installer" or the 64-bit "Windows x86-64 executable installer".

Comment: Before running anything on top of python, it is a good idea to make sure that python runs.  If there is a problem running IDLE from an icon, try starting it from python with `import idlelib.idle` or from Command Prompt wtih `python -m idlelib`.  Either way, you may see some IDLE specific error messages that will give a clue to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While this won't help you get IDLE open, I would strongly suggest looking into using another IDE, such as Pycharm's free edition.

Comment: I'm unable to post comments @martineau otherwise I would have.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Changing editors will not help if Python is not installed correctly.